# How to access index.js res property from an html script tag

Tags: javascript, html, express

i need an hand with the following  access var problem.

I have two files, an index.js and a page.ejs, these needs me for a timer creation linked with  datetimes rested in my local server.

```
//index.js..
    router.get('/mieiNoleggi', function(req,res,next){
        res.render("landMieiNoleggi",{title: 'miei noleggi', utente_loggato : req.session.utente, noleggi : req.session.mieiNoleggi, rimanenti : timer})
      })



//page.ejs

  <span id="d"><%- rimanenti.t_d %></span>
                                  <span id="h"><%- rimanenti.t_h %></span>
                                  <span id="m"><%- rimanenti.t_m %></span>
                                  <span id="s"><%- rimanenti.t_s %></span>
                                  
                         

                                  <script>
                                    a = rimanenti.t_s;
                                    document.getElementById("d").textContent = a ;
                                  </script>
```

I can access res property 'rimanenti'(on index.js) with expression tags <%..%> in page.ejs, but if I want access it in script tag i cannot. I need to do it for activate the timers. someone knows how to accomplish this. pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `<script>` tags, you can use EJS expression tags only within Strings. Assuming the property `rimanenti.t_s` is defined, you can try this on your EJS page:

```
<script>
  a = parseInt("<%= rimanenti.t_s %>");
  // use Number() or parseFloat() if rimanenti.t_s is not meant to be an int
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the script tag also you need to embed the `rimanenti.t_s` value.

```
<script>
  a = <%= rimanenti.t_d %>;
  document.getElementById("d").textContent = a;
</script>
```

PS. Try to avoid using `<%-` instead of `<%=` in the HTML. 
The first one is passing the unescaped value into the template, which can make some security issue in your code.